# Accessing parent info with mustache php (two or more while cycles)

Tags: php, while-loop, mustache, cycle

In first sorry for my bad english.
I'm using mustache PHP and i started topic in github already - https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/issues/396

I have 2 while cycles, here is the code:

```
$query_check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->argos_db_prefix."tickets ORDER by id DESC LIMIT {$pagination['limit']['first']}, {$pagination['limit']['second']}");
$ticket_admin_form_array=[];//globalize
$ticket_admin_form_array2 = [];//globalize
$count = 0; //globalize
if ($query_check->rowCount() > 0) {
    $tickets_found = true; //we found results
    while ($row=$query_check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $tid = $row['id'];
        $tq = $row['question'];
        $open = $row['open'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $date = date('d.m.y H:i:s', $row['date']);
        $text = $row['text'];
        
        $ticket_admin_form_array[]=[
            'ext_the_tickets_tid'=>$tid,
            'ext_the_tickets_cat'=>$category,
            'ext_the_tickets_tq'=>$tq, //question
            'ext_the_tickets_open_s'=>$open,
            'ext_the_tickets_username'=>$username,
            'ext_the_tickets_date'=>$date,
            'ext_the_tickets_text'=>$text,
        ];
        
        
        $get_all_msgs = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->argos_db_prefix."tickets_comments WHERE tid='$tid' order by id ASC");
        while ($row = $get_all_msgs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $textt = $row['text'];
            $datet = date('d.m.y H:i:s', $row['date']);
            $authored = $row['authored'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            if ($authored == 1) {
                $authored = "($username):";
            } else {
                $authored = "<span style='color:red'>Administrator:</span>";
            }
            
            $count++; //we count the results and passing to array below

             
            $ticket_admin_form_array2[$count][$tid]=[
                'ext_the_tickets_authored'=>$authored,
                'ext_the_tickets_datec'=>$datet,
                'ext_the_tickets_textc'=>$textt,
            ];
        }
```

My template file is:

```
{{#all_tickets_arr1}}
<div class="tickets_box t_{{ext_the_tickets_tid}}">[{{ext_the_tickets_cat}}] {{ext_the_tickets_tq}} | {{ext_the_tickets_lang_date}}: {{ext_the_tickets_date}} | {{ext_the_tickets_lang_status}}: 

</div>
<div class="t_container_style t_cont_{{ext_the_tickets_tid}}" style="display:none">
<div class="t_new_msg_body">({{ext_the_tickets_username}}): ({{ext_the_tickets_date}}): <br/>{{ext_the_tickets_text}}</div>


{{#all_tickets_arr2}}
<div class="t_new_msg_body">{{&ext_the_tickets_authored}} ({{ext_the_tickets_datec}}): <br/>{{ext_the_tickets_textc}}</div>
{{/all_tickets_arr2}}


</div>
{{/all_tickets_arr1}}
```

i want to get unique results for every ticket. Now i get the same comments in every ticket which i started. In bottom i have this:

```
return $this->m->render(file_get_contents("ext/pok4/the_tickets/template/admin_form.html"), [
    'all_tickets_arr1'=> new ArrayIterator($ticket_admin_form_array),
    'all_tickets_arr2'=> new ArrayIterator($ticket_admin_form_array2),
    'ext_the_tickets_pagination'=>($tickets_found) ? $pagination['output'] : '',
    'ext_the_tickets_found_results'=>$tickets_found,
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_date'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_date'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_status'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_status'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_welcome'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_welcome'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_open'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_open'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_closed'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_closed'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_send'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_send'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_ticket_closed_adm'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_ticket_closed'],
    'ext_the_tickets_lang_not_found'=>$this->lang['ext_the_tickets_no_tickets_for_now'],
]);
```

I use two array iterrators to passing it to mustache php.

```
'all_tickets_arr1'=> new ArrayIterator($ticket_admin_form_array),
'all_tickets_arr2'=> new ArrayIterator($ticket_admin_form_array2),
```

i want to to use ticket_id ($tid) and $count in templates for all_tickets_arr2 to get unique results for every ticket (unique comments i mean)
Now as i said every ticket have the same comments.

The problem is here:

```
{{#all_tickets_arr2}}
<div class="t_new_msg_body">{{&ext_the_tickets_authored}} ({{ext_the_tickets_datec}}): <br/>{{ext_the_tickets_textc}}</div>
{{/all_tickets_arr2}}
```

this one must be something like this:

```
{{#all_tickets_arr2.count.tid}}
<div class="t_new_msg_body">{{&ext_the_tickets_authored}} ({{ext_the_tickets_datec}}): <br/>{{ext_the_tickets_textc}}</div>
{{/all_tickets_arr2.count.tid}}
```

i think... ? :)

can someone give me a advice what to do to make comments to show for every ticket uniquely ?